# Ciclo con 2 contadores en Java

Tags: java, loops

¿Es válido hacer un ciclo como este?

```
for(i=0,j=0;a[i][j]==0;i++,j++)
```

¿Incrementaría ambas variables con cada iteracion realizada?

Comment: Si no mal recuerdo, la respuesta es si, si las incrementa. Lo has probado? Te ha dado algun error?

Comment: Es correcto, pero recuerda que te va incrementar ambas posiciones es decir tomarías valores 0,0 1,1, 2,2 3,3 etc... estarías dejando valores en posiciones 0,1 0,2 etc...

Comment: Lo probé y no da ningún error, pero tampoco cumple la función que esperaba. Pensé que podía ser porque no estaba permitido darle esos argumentos, pero si no es eso, el problema debe estar en otro lado. Gracias por ayudar.

Comment: M. Gress, sí, estoy tratando de hacer un ajedrez y serían las casillas que puede amenazar el alfil.

Comment: Nacho es bueno tenerte por aquí, bienvenido, te sugiero revises [ask], para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Realiza también el [tour].

Comment: Hola Jorgesys. Muchas gracias! Voy a informarme sobre eso que decís. Recién estoy arrancando en esto de la programación, espero, en algún momento, poder contribuir un poco también. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo como:

```
int j = 0;
for(int i=0;a[i][j]==0;i++){
//Código
j++;
}
```

Solo recuerda hacer `j++` al final del ciclo.